# Cannot generate Ethereum address from private key

Tags: addresses, private-key, cryptography, keccak, ecdsa

I am trying to use the [Bitcoin ECDSA Library](https://github.com/bitcoin-core/secp256k1) to generate an Ethereum address from a private key. I took the private key from my Metamask wallet then used the following code to generate the public key.

```
secp256k1_pubkey pubkey;
unsigned char seckey[32];
// initialize secret key with value from metamask
secp256k1_context* ctx = secp256k1_context_create(SECP256K1_CONTEXT_SIGN | SECP256K1_CONTEXT_VERIFY);
secp256k1_context_randomize(ctx, randomize);
secp256k1_ec_pubkey_create(ctx, &pubkey, seckey);
// use pubkey
```

I then run the public key through [Keccak-256](https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/keccak_256.html) (with Input type = hex) and take the last 20 bytes as stated in Appendix F of the [yellow paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf).

However I get a different value than the public address I can see in my Metamask wallet. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must serialize the public key before use like so:

```
unsigned char uncompressed_pubkey[65];
secp256k1_ec_pubkey_serialize(ctx, uncompressed_pubkey, &len, &pubkey, SECP256K1_EC_UNCOMPRESSED);
```

Now take the last 64 bytes of uncompressed_pubkey and run Keccak-256 on it as before.